# query single table instead of all relational tables when using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We need to query user by userid to execute every web request to make sure the user exist. Every time it queries, it joins with other relational tables. How to avoid it? I just want to query only user table. I set the Fetz Type lazy for attachment table, but it still joins the attachment table. What i'm missing?

## Log

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_6_, user0_.time_created as time_cre2_6_, user0_.uuid as uuid3_6_, user0_.version as version4_6_, user0_.email_address as email_ad5_6_, user0_.first_name as first_na6_6_, user0_.hashed_password as hashed_p7_6_, user0_.is_verified as is_verif8_6_, user0_.last_name as last_nam9_6_, user0_.photo_id as photo_i10_6_, user0_.public_id as public_11_6_, user0_.role as role12_6_, user0_.user_status as user_st13_6_ from user user0_ where user0_.email_address=?
Hibernate: select socialuser0_.user_id as user_id15_6_1_, socialuser0_.id as id1_5_1_, socialuser0_.id as id1_5_0_, socialuser0_.time_created as time_cre2_5_0_, socialuser0_.uuid as uuid3_5_0_, socialuser0_.version as version4_5_0_, socialuser0_.access_token as access_t5_5_0_, socialuser0_.display_name as display_6_5_0_, socialuser0_.expire_time as expire_t7_5_0_, socialuser0_.image_url as image_ur8_5_0_, socialuser0_.profile_url as profile_9_5_0_, socialuser0_.provider_id as provide10_5_0_, socialuser0_.provider_user_id as provide11_5_0_, socialuser0_.rank as rank12_5_0_, socialuser0_.refresh_token as refresh13_5_0_, socialuser0_.secret as secret14_5_0_, socialuser0_.user_id as user_id15_5_0_ from social_user socialuser0_ where socialuser0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select sessions0_.user_id as user_id6_6_1_, sessions0_.id as id1_4_1_, sessions0_.id as id1_4_0_, sessions0_.is_keep_logged_in as is_keep_2_4_0_, sessions0_.last_updated as last_upd3_4_0_, sessions0_.time_created as time_cre4_4_0_, sessions0_.token as token5_4_0_, sessions0_.user_id as user_id6_4_0_ from session_token sessions0_ where sessions0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_6_1_, user0_.time_created as time_cre2_6_1_, user0_.uuid as uuid3_6_1_, user0_.version as version4_6_1_, user0_.email_address as email_ad5_6_1_, user0_.first_name as first_na6_6_1_, user0_.hashed_password as hashed_p7_6_1_, user0_.is_verified as is_verif8_6_1_, user0_.last_name as last_nam9_6_1_, user0_.photo_id as photo_i10_6_1_, user0_.public_id as public_11_6_1_, user0_.role as role12_6_1_, user0_.user_status as user_st13_6_1_, attachment1_.user_id as user_id18_6_3_, attachment1_.id as id1_0_3_, attachment1_.id as id1_0_0_, attachment1_.time_created as time_cre2_0_0_, attachment1_.uuid as uuid3_0_0_, attachment1_.version as version4_0_0_, attachment1_.attachment_date as attachme5_0_0_, attachment1_.attachment_size as attachme6_0_0_, attachment1_.attachment_type as attachme7_0_0_, attachment1_.attachment_url as attachme8_0_0_, attachment1_.file_id as file_id9_0_0_, attachment1_.images_generated as images_10_0_0_, attachment1_.mime_type as mime_ty11_0_0_, attachment1_.playback_formats as playbac12_0_0_, attachment1_.ready_for_playback as ready_f13_0_0_, attachment1_.secured as secured14_0_0_, attachment1_.title as title15_0_0_, attachment1_.total_pages as total_p16_0_0_, attachment1_.user_id as user_id18_0_0_, attachment1_.virus_status as virus_s17_0_0_ from user user0_ left outer join attachment attachment1_ on user0_.id=attachment1_.user_id where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select pages0_.attachment as attachme1_0_3_, pages0_.pages as pages2_2_3_, attachment1_.id as id1_1_0_, attachment1_.attachment_id as attachme6_1_0_, attachment1_.file_id as file_id2_1_0_, attachment1_.mime_type as mime_typ3_1_0_, attachment1_.page_number as page_num4_1_0_, attachment1_.page_type as page_typ5_1_0_, attachment2_.id as id1_0_1_, attachment2_.time_created as time_cre2_0_1_, attachment2_.uuid as uuid3_0_1_, attachment2_.version as version4_0_1_, attachment2_.attachment_date as attachme5_0_1_, attachment2_.attachment_size as attachme6_0_1_, attachment2_.attachment_type as attachme7_0_1_, attachment2_.attachment_url as attachme8_0_1_, attachment2_.file_id as file_id9_0_1_, attachment2_.images_generated as images_10_0_1_, attachment2_.mime_type as mime_ty11_0_1_, attachment2_.playback_formats as playbac12_0_1_, attachment2_.ready_for_playback as ready_f13_0_1_, attachment2_.secured as secured14_0_1_, attachment2_.title as title15_0_1_, attachment2_.total_pages as total_p16_0_1_, attachment2_.user_id as user_id18_0_1_, attachment2_.virus_status as virus_s17_0_1_, user3_.id as id1_6_2_, user3_.time_created as time_cre2_6_2_, user3_.uuid as uuid3_6_2_, user3_.version as version4_6_2_, user3_.email_address as email_ad5_6_2_, user3_.first_name as first_na6_6_2_, user3_.hashed_password as hashed_p7_6_2_, user3_.is_verified as is_verif8_6_2_, user3_.last_name as last_nam9_6_2_, user3_.photo_id as photo_i10_6_2_, user3_.public_id as public_11_6_2_, user3_.role as role12_6_2_, user3_.user_status as user_st13_6_2_ from attachment_pages pages0_ inner join attachment_has_pages attachment1_ on pages0_.pages=attachment1_.id left outer join attachment attachment2_ on attachment1_.attachment_id=attachment2_.id left outer join user user3_ on attachment2_.user_id=user3_.id where pages0_.attachment=?
Hibernate: select sessiontok0_.id as id1_4_0_, sessiontok0_.is_keep_logged_in as is_keep_2_4_0_, sessiontok0_.last_updated as last_upd3_4_0_, sessiontok0_.time_created as time_cre4_4_0_, sessiontok0_.token as token5_4_0_, sessiontok0_.user_id as user_id6_4_0_ from session_token sessiontok0_ where sessiontok0_.id=?
Hibernate: select sessiontok0_.id as id1_4_0_, sessiontok0_.is_keep_logged_in as is_keep_2_4_0_, sessiontok0_.last_updated as last_upd3_4_0_, sessiontok0_.time_created as time_cre4_4_0_, sessiontok0_.token as token5_4_0_, sessiontok0_.user_id as user_id6_4_0_ from session_token sessiontok0_ where sessiontok0_.id=?
Hibernate: select sessiontok0_.id as id1_4_0_, sessiontok0_.is_keep_logged_in as is_keep_2_4_0_, sessiontok0_.last_updated as last_upd3_4_0_, sessiontok0_.time_created as time_cre4_4_0_, sessiontok0_.token as token5_4_0_, sessiontok0_.user_id as user_id6_4_0_ from session_token sessiontok0_ where sessiontok0_.id=?
sessiontok0_.user_id as user_id6_4_0_ from session_token sessiontok0_ where sessiontok0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into session_token (is_keep_logged_in, last_updated, time_created, token, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select sessions0_.user_id as user_id6_6_1_, sessions0_.id as id1_4_1_, sessions0_.id as id1_4_0_, sessions0_.is_keep_logged_in as is_keep_2_4_0_, sessions0_.last_updated as last_upd3_4_0_, sessions0_.time_created as time_cre4_4_0_, sessions0_.token as token5_4_0_, sessions0_.user_id as user_id6_4_0_ from session_token sessions0_ where sessions0_.user_id=?
```

## User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String emailAddress;

    private String hashedPassword;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = SessionToken.class, orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<SessionToken> sessions = Collections
        .synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet<SessionToken>(Collections
                .<SessionToken> reverseOrder()));

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = Attachment.class, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
private List<Attachment> attachment = new ArrayList<Attachment>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = VerificationToken.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
private List<VerificationToken> verificationTokens = new ArrayList<VerificationToken>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<SocialUser> socialUsers = new HashSet<SocialUser>();


....
}
```

## UserRepo class

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select u from User u where uuid = ?")
    User findByUuid(String uuid);

}
```

Comment: Hint: LazyCollection(FALSE) means that the collection is NOT lazy. That's why the sessions and verification tokens are loaded. Your log doesn't show the complete last query, so we don't know what it is.

Comment: @JBNizet It is pulling atachment even if LazyColection is TRUE.

Comment: You seem to have a list of attachments in another entity. If you posted the complete SQL query, we could know what it loads and why. But you still haven't.

Comment: @JBNizet I pasted the entire log. Also set LazyCOllection to true but still queries all the relational tables.

Comment: What is the complete code causing all these queries to be executed? What are you doing with the user once it's loaded?

Comment: I agree with @JB Nizet.  The attachments are not loaded until right after a second query of the user table.  You are requesting these objects somewhere in your code after the initial login code is run.  Step through the code an watch the logs until the sql statements querying the attachments appear.